# How to reverse all words in line with sed?

Tags: sed, reverse, cpu-word

For example, we have:

```
This is the song that doesn`t end
```

What sed command will turn it into this?

```
end doesn`t that song the is This
```

I've found only how to reverse lines in a file (a.k.a. `tac`):

```
sed -n '1!G;h;$p'
```

Comment: Why would you think sed would be a reasonable choice for this? sed is for `s/old/new/`, that is all.

Comment: You could adapt [this sed script](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Reverse-chars-of-lines) to swap words instead of characters, but it's almost certainly going to be a brittle, unreadable mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'G;:a;s/^(\S+)(\s*)(.*\n)/\3\2\1/;ta;s/\n//' file
```

Append a newline as a delimiter. Split the current line into three and prepend the first word, the following space and the remainder of the line following the newline in that order. Iterate until the pattern matching fails and then remove the introduced newline.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{for(i=NF;i>0;i--){printf("%s%s",$i,(i>1?OFS:ORS))}}'  Input_file
```